# skipping adding constructors when inheriting from std::string class

Tags: c++, c++11

Tried to argument the std::string so that it supports  method "bool operator==(int)".  I got errors:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 te2.cc
te2.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
te2.cc:20:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘mstring::mstring(const char [4])’
te2.cc:20:20: note: candidates are:
te2.cc:10:7: note: mstring::mstring()
te2.cc:10:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
te2.cc:10:7: note: mstring::mstring(const mstring&)
te2.cc:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [4]’ to ‘const mstring&’
te2.cc:10:7: note: mstring::mstring(mstring&&)
te2.cc:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [4]’ to ‘mstring&&’
```

Here is the simple source:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class mstring : public string {
public:
    //mstring (char* p) : std::string(p) {};
    bool operator == (int x) {
        int n = atoi(this->c_str());
        return (n == x);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mstring t("123");
    if (t == atoi(argv[1])) {
        printf("yes\n");
    } else {
        printf("no\n");
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the constructor `/mstring (char* p) : std::string(p) {};`, then it compiles and runs fine.

The question is, if it possible to make it work without defining the constructors for mstring, just use the whatever the constructors of the base class (there is no new data member anyway)?   Thanks.

Comment: Usually inheriting classes from the `std` namespace is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: You can define `operator==(const std::string&, int)` as a standalone, non-member function, if you are so inclined. In fact, you likely want it this way - you probably also want a symmetrical `operator==(int, const std::string&)`, which can't be a member function anyhow.

Comment: You don't need to convert argv[1] to int. Compare it directly to a std::string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about providing a free standing operator function instead of inheriting from `std::string` (which makes that code more usable overall):

```
bool operator==(const std::string& s, int i) {
    int n = atoi(s.c_str());
    return (n == i);
}

bool operator==(int i, const std::string& s) {
    return s == i;
}
```

Or even more generic:

```
template<typename T>
bool operator==(const std::string& s, T t) {
    std::istringstream iss;
    iss << t;
    return (s == iss.str());
}
```

---

Classes from the `std` namespace aren't intended to be inherited, but just used in interfaces and function parameters. Inheriting from those classes makes your code less usable, since clients need to use your implementation instead of just using the `std` type.

---

Also note: For your particular use case it's not necessary to convert anything at all, unless you want to assert that `argv[1]` contains a number (where `atoi()` certainly isn't the best method to do so, look up [`stoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead). You can just compare the strings:

```
if (std::string("123") == argv[1]) {
    printf("yes\n");
} else {
    printf("no\n");
}
```

Comment: That's the perfect solution. Seen it before but it didn't occur to me until I see your solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can explicitly inherit the constructors by adding

```
using string::string;
```

in your class